# Powershell Has Stopped Working

Tags: powershell

When I run powershell I get the error:

> powershell has stopped working

There doesn't seem to be any relevant errors in the EventLog.
I get this when I run powershell as an admin or a normal user.

When I try to re-install the Windows Management Framework I get the error:

> A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file

This all seemed to happen when I tried to set a remote execution policy (to Unrestricted)

Any suggestions on how to resolve/troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I just remembered that I also edited the local group policy (Turn on Script Execution and Turn on Powershell Transcription).  When I set those back to Not configured it resolved the issue.